# C# Quick Question: Why putting Animator infront of anim gives error?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, animation

How come this code works:

```
private Animator anim;

void Start()
{
   anim = GetComponent<Animator>();
}
```

While this code dosen't:

```
private Animator anim;

void Start()
{
    Animator anim = GetComponent<Animator>();
}
```

Comment: Maybe its my old eyes, but those blocks look the same. Is the first block suppose to have a var in it instead?

Comment: @DougDawson , OP already has a class/script variable of that name!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very simple,

with this line of code

```
private Animator anim;
```

you are making a variable named "anim"

That applies to the WHOLE SCRIPT.

Then you are trying to make ANOTHER variable ALSO named "anim" inside "Start".

It's an age-old gotchya  :)

THIS means make a new variable named "anim":

```
void Start()
{
    Animator anim = GetComponent<Animator>();
}
```

But THIS means use the existing variable named "anim":

```
void Start()
{
   anim = GetComponent<Animator>();
}
```

You can NOT say "make a new variable named 'anim'" because ***there is already a variable in the whole script*** named 'anim' !